# SharePoint 2013 managed navigation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have developed an application in SP 2013 in which I have used managed navigation term store. When I access my site by login to server managed navigation works fine but when I hit my site using public IP managed navigation doesn't work. I have created alternative access mapping of my site i.e www.abc.com, when I use this domain name on the server it works fine. My assumption is this when I will add this IP in DNS it will work fine, am I right or I have to do something else?

Comment: Error loading navigation: The Web application at  could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add entry in hosts file (c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) of the station from which you are testing:
IP www.abc.com

Test from the station. If it works, go with adding the IP to DNS. If it doesn't work as expected, something else should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark. Try defining the public FQDN as Default in Alternate Access Mappings.